# Importing timeSeries from csv file into R with correct dates

Tags: r, time-series

I have looked all over the internet to find an answer to my problem and failed.

I am using R with the [Rmetrics](https://www.rmetrics.org) package.

I tried reading my own `dataset.csv` via the `readSeries` function but sadly the dates I entered are not imported correctly, now every row has the current date.

I tried using their sample data sets, exported them to csv and re-imported an it creates the same problem.

You can test it using this code:

```
data <- head(SWX.RET[,1:3])
write.csv(data, file="myData.csv")
data2 <- readSeries(file="myData.csv",header=T,sep=",")
```

If you now check the `data2` time series you will notice that the row date is the current date.

I am confused why this is and what to do to fix it.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with the extra option `row.names=FALSE` to the `write.csv()` functions; see its help page for details.  Here is a worked example:

```
R> fakeData <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date()+seq(-7,-1), value=runif(7))
R> fakeData
        date    value
1 2011-02-14 0.261088
2 2011-02-15 0.514413
3 2011-02-16 0.675607
4 2011-02-17 0.982817
5 2011-02-18 0.759544
6 2011-02-19 0.566488
7 2011-02-20 0.849690
R> write.csv(fakeData, "/tmp/fakeDate.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
R> readSeries("/tmp/fakeDate.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
GMT
              value
2011-02-14 0.261088
2011-02-15 0.514413
2011-02-16 0.675607
2011-02-17 0.982817
2011-02-18 0.759544
2011-02-19 0.566488
2011-02-20 0.849690
R>
```

Comment: This is what I get when I run your code:
`> readSeries("fakeDate.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

         value

[1,] 0.7631120
[2,] 0.8262407
[3,] 0.4339850
[4,] 0.7790393
[5,] 0.3257912
[6,] 0.9497101
[7,] 0.2882622`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The somehow you don't have a date field. Why? Was a date column written out to the file?

Comment: Yes, there is a date column in the exported csv. This weird problem has been bugging me for a week now and according to google I am the only one who has it! I have the R version 2.12.1 btw. Again you help is much appreciated!

Comment: Well, I wasn't faking the above. It is genuine cut&paste. Do you have a strange locale set which would confuse date parsing?  Also try another `read*` routine --- such as `read.csv()` followed by `strptime()`.

Comment: My locale is `"LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"` I tried using a read.csv which works as advertized, I however need this data set as a time series object (S4). Apparently this should all be very easy, so I suspect the error to be with my setup somewhere.

Comment: The use `read.csv()` and construct the series by hand, this works here: `fdf <- read.csv("/tmp/fakeDate.csv"); timeSeries(fdf[,-1], as.Date(fdf[,1]))`.

Comment: Interesting solution, sadly it does not solve all of my problems, as `class(fdf)` still returns `"data.frame"`. This is a Problem once I try to plug the data set into the `portfolioFrontier()` function, which requires a timeSeries object. I am confused, but since for you the readSeries function does work as promised, the problem **has** to be with my rig.

Comment: Well: `fdf()` is a data.frame as that is what `read.csv` returns. My second command ran `timeSeries()`; just assign that to a variable.

Comment: Thank you! I have to admit I feel rather stupid for having thought of that myself. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @flOw, use text editor, go into the CSV file and delete the word "date" and then run the `timeSeries` again.  This should work.